# sorry-cypress screenshots and videos upload not working on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, docker-compose, cypress, sorrycypress

I have been trying to configure this open-source sorry-cypress dashboard for our Cypress web testing for the last three days. Until today I cannot upload, download or show screenshots and videos made by Cypress during tests and show them in the sorry-cypress dashboard.

I am running Windows 11 with Docker Desktop

I carefully followed their documentation on how to set up a Full sorry-cypress on-demand build using Docker. The dashboard, director, API, and MongoDB are running on my computer and I am accessing them through https://localhost:<port>. The dashboard is showing test executions that are running and test results correctly, but the screenshots and videos are not shown.

After a few unsuccessful builds with MinIO as my screenshot driver, I switched to Amazon AWS S3 driver. I followed the steps shown here, so I created one user and gave him basic permissions to access my newly created bucket and also set the bucket to be public. After all of this, the bucket is still empty after I run my tests and the dashboard is still without pictures and videos.

I was able to observe, that the link of the image shown on the dashboard is missing my AWS S3_REGION Environment Variable set in docker.yml

1. the sorry-cypress dashboard is pointing at this link

   ```
   https://tportal-tests-dashboard.s3.amazonaws.com/c7bb5026f575dc63da0f95e6be5883c7.png
   ```
2. my AWS S3 link to one manually uploaded picture looks something like this

   ```
   https://tportal-tests-dashboard.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/c7bb5026f575dc63da0f95e6be5883c7.png
   ```

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY are set correctly (I checked this by looking at the AWS dashboard when they were last used.

Test execution I am running with this command:

```
npx cypress-cloud --parallel --record --key Ij0RfK --ci-build-id skap7
```

#### **What else do I need to set up so the sorry-cypress-director will be able to access AWS, upload screenshots and videos, and show them in the dashboard, pls?**

This is my configuration:

1. my `docker-compose.full.yml` downloaded from [sorry-cypress](https://github.com/sorry-cypress/sorry-cypress) git

   ```
   version: '3.6'

   services:
     mongo:
       image: 'mongo:4.4'
       volumes:
         - ./data/data-mongo-cypress:/data/db

     director:
       image: 'agoldis/sorry-cypress-director:latest'
       environment:
         DASHBOARD_URL: 'http://localhost:8080'
         MONGODB_URI: 'mongodb://mongo:27017'
         MONGODB_DATABASE: 'sorry-cypress'
         EXECUTION_DRIVER: '../execution/mongo/driver'
         SCREENSHOTS_DRIVER: '../screenshots/s3.driver'
         GITLAB_JOB_RETRIES: 'false'
         AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: '<set from AWS>'
         AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: '<set from AWS>'
         S3_BUCKET: 'tportal-tests-dashboard'
         S3_REGION: 'eu-central-1'
         S3_ACL: 'public-read'

         PROBE_LOGGER: 'true'
       ports:
         - 1234:1234
       depends_on:
         - mongo

     api:
       image: 'agoldis/sorry-cypress-api:latest'
       environment:
         MONGODB_URI: 'mongodb://mongo:27017'
         MONGODB_DATABASE: 'sorry-cypress'
         APOLLO_PLAYGROUND: 'false'
       ports:
         - 4000:4000
       depends_on:
         - mongo

     dashboard:
       image: 'agoldis/sorry-cypress-dashboard:latest'
       environment:
         GRAPHQL_SCHEMA_URL: 'http://localhost:4000'
         GRAPHQL_CLIENT_CREDENTIALS: ''
         CI_URL: ''
         PORT: 8080
       ports:
         - 8080:8080
       depends_on:
         - mongo
         - api
   ```
2. AWS bucket policy

   ```
   {
       "Version": "2012-10-17",
       "Statement": [
           {
               "Sid": "SorryCypressUpload",
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Principal": {
                   "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::6538********:user/sorry-cypress_dashboard"
               },
               "Action": [
                   "s3:PutObject",
                   "s3:PutObjectAcl"
               ],
               "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::tportal-tests-dashboard/*"
           }
       ]
   }
   ```
3. AWS user permissions policies

   ```
   {
       "Version": "2012-10-17",
       "Statement": [
           {
               "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Action": [
                   "s3:PutObject",
                   "s3:PutObjectAcl"
               ],
               "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::tportal-tests-dashboard/*"
           }
       ]
   }
   ```
4. cypress test `cypress.config.js`

   ```
   const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
   const { cloudPlugin } = require("cypress-cloud/plugin");

   module.exports = defineConfig({
     projectId: "Ij0RfK",
     // setupNodeEvents can be defined in either
     // the e2e or component configuration

     e2e: {
       baseUrl: "https://localhost:44415/create-account/",
       viewportHeight: 900,
       viewportWidth: 1440,
       scrollBehavior: false,
       defaultCommandTimeout: 500,
       setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
         return cloudPlugin(on, config);
       },
     },

     $schema: "https://on.cypress.io/cypress.schema.json",
   });
   ```
5. cypress test `currents.config.js`

   ```
   // currents.config.js
   module.exports = {
     projectId: "Ij0RfK",
     recordKey: "xxx",
     // Sorry Cypress users - set the director service URL
     cloudServiceUrl: "http://localhost:1234/",
   };
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I don't know what happened, but after the weekend, I tried to execute some more tests, and the screenshots and the videos are now shown in the sorry-cypress dashboard and also in my AWS S3 bucket.

Maybe it needed some time to eat new credentials, or after so many changes, it just needed some reset to forget all previous changes.